# Nodejs sessions undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I can set the session variables to output straight away, however if I access the route again (without even refreshing the page) the var becomes undefined again. What am I missing? How can I keep the var even when the page has been refreshed?

In app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: 'asecret',
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    expires: false, // Alive Until Browser Exits
    httpOnly: true
  }}));
```

In Index.js

```
var sess ="";

router.get('/getSubmit', function(req, res){
    var socket = req.app.get('socketio');
    sess = req.session;

   sess.avar = "stuff";
   console.log(sess.avar); //prints 

  console.log(sess.test); //will not ever print although has been set
  if (sess.test == undefined) {
      sess.test = "stuff"; 
      console.log(sess.test); //prints
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have something else altering `session`? With the following snippet, I wasn't able to reproduce the error you described. http://pastebin.com/5Bpjr6MX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using socket.io add:

```
sess.save(function(err) {

    })
```

To the end of the get.